Does Pick’s Theorem Hold Up In Larger Border Points as They Tend to Infinity?
I was wondering if Pick’s Theorem still works as the number of Border points (B) tends to infinity (or $\displaystyle \lim_{b \to \infty} A=\frac{b}{2}+i+h-1=\infty$ or even the possibility of $\displaystyle\lim_{b \to \infty} A=\frac{b}{2}+i+h-1=undefined$ since math doesn’t work the same with $\infty$)? With what I have tested out as B gets larger, and even though the Interior points (I) stays small and finite (for example $i=10$), the Area (A) of the polygon suddenly grows massively larger and larger. I am assuming on something like the Mandelbrot Set, with it’s infinite perimeter and finite area, Pick’s Theorem wouldn’t work in the intended way.

Pick's theorem works, and makes sense, for finite polygons.

@MichalAdamaszek I am just wondering and assuming as B gets closer to infinity and “becomes” infinity, would Pick’s Theorem still work? I used the Mandelbrot Set as an example, but any fractal or any shape with a finite area and infinite border, most likely wouldn’t work for Pick’s Theorem since the area would probably go to infinity because of the infinite border points. In a way I am also asking would the area go to infinity if the border points would be infinity (even though the area should be finite as proven with fractals).

Pick's theorem is for polygons with lattice points as vertices, not for fractals.

@Lucenaposition That explains the $\infty$ result then, I honestly forgot about that and thought it was really weird that it sort of broke with fractals, thanks!
